# if there is an exception in the "using" will it be automatically closed

Tags: c#, vb.net

Because I am using a "using" here, If there is an exception any where in the TRY will the FtpWebRequest, FtpWebRespons and responseStream automatically be closed?

```
Try
 Dim request As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(""), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("", "")
        Using response As FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

            Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)


                    TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
                    TextBox1.Text += vbNewLine 
                    TextBox1.Text += vbNewLine
                    ' Use the + for appending (set the textbox to multiline)

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using    

Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
End Try
```

Comment: To test that yourself, create a class implementing `IDisposable`, and write a message to the console in the `Dispose`  method (or put a breakpoint)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they will be disposed of except for when there is a Stack Overflow.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> A Using block behaves like a Try...Finally construction in which the
>   Try block uses the resources and the Finally block disposes of them.
>   Because of this, the Using block guarantees disposal of the resources,
>   no matter how you exit the block. This is true even in the case of an
>   unhandled exception, except for a StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, all three will be closed.

The `Using` statement ends up calling the `Dipose` method on classes that implement `IDisposable` (this happens in a `Finally` section that the compiler generates). In this case, these classes will close when `Dispose` is called.

There are very few exceptions to this - if the process exits (say by calling `Environment.Exit` in the body of the `Using` statements), then the `Finally` block and disposal are not going to happen.

Comment: Hah, sorry, i should have been more clear, i was more focusing on exits vs exists...

Answer (score 5):

They will 'automatically' be disposed; if disposing closes a thing that can be opened, then yes.